# Phase-shift a Broadband Time-Domain Function

Tags: signal-processing, fourier, phase-shift, phasor

Suppose we have an operator \$A_\phi\$ which phase-shifts a sinusoid by \$\phi\$:

$$A_\phi[\cos(\omega t)] = \cos(\omega t + \phi)$$

In phasor domain, \$A_\phi = e^{+j\phi}\$ is a complex constant.

I am having trouble understanding how \$A_\phi\$ operates on a generic (broadband) time-domain function \$f(t)\$ (whose shape is known entirely a priori):

$$A_\phi[f(t)] = \quad ?$$

I was thinking that I could Fourier-transform \$f(t)\$ to decompose it into a continuum of sinusoids, but these are not true phasors, since when you multiply the Fourier transform by \$e^{+j\phi}\$, it acts as a regular multiplication, not a phase shift. How can I phase-shift a generally broadband function in time domain?

Comment: You need to use `\$` to start and end in-line mathjax on this SE.

Comment: Argon, why do you want to do this?

Comment: @andy I am modelling the behaviour of a broadband current source, which is given as a (spatially-dependent) phasor. I can do it at a certain frrequency trivially, but when I want the source to span a frequency continuum I run into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

A particular example of your operator is \$\phi=-\pi/2\$ which produces the [Hilbert Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform). You *could* implement it by taking the Fourier transform and phase shifting each component by something which kind of depends on \$\omega\$... negative frequencies are shifted by the opposite phase. This really is a non-trivial operation because you need to integrate over \$\omega\$ to recover the original signal. The problem is that this process is not causal. I would suggest searching for "zero-phase digital filter" or "digital Hilbert transform"; you will find many techniques for achieving approximate constant phase shift in a particular pass band with either FIR or IIR approaches. For instance, [JOS has some material](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/sasp/Hilbert_Transform_Design_Example.html).

More generally, one can define an [all-pass filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-pass_filter) as any filter with unity gain at all frequencies.

Comment: What would a constant-phase all-pass filter be? A complex exponential constant? Wouldn't this be the same as phase-shifting each component of the Fourier transform?

Comment: Almost... there's a sign problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Relationship_with_the_Fourier_transform

Comment: Thanks for the help! As I understand from Wikipedia: If I convert the function \$f\$ into an analytic one \$F\$ by adding j*Hilbert transform, then it has only positive frequencies t. Then, would this issue arise still? A complex multiplication in frequency domain corresponds to the same thing in time domain, but then I'd take the real part like with an ordinary phasor: \$\operatorname{Re} (e^{j\phi} F)\$.

Comment: But if you start with a real signal, then how do process it to create a signal with only positive frequencies? You've just shifted the problem around. There's no free lunch (i.e. no simple time domain representation) if you need causality. Look at the link to JOS's example. Do you need causality?

Comment: the function \$f(t)\$ is known for all time a priori—noncausality is not an issue.